# Preface in Overleaf

Tags: books

I must create a PREFACE on Overleaf. Does a tex-command exist?

(I use `\documentclass[]{book}`)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried `\chapter{Preface}` in the `\frontmatter` part of the document?

Comment: Overleaf is completely unrelated to this question (you might want to change the title to "preface in book class"  (but `\chapter*{Preface}` possibly followed by `\mainmatter` before your main chapters.  Overleaf runs a standard texlive tex installation so the tex commands available on Overleaf are the same as those available elsewhere

Comment: For example: \usepackage{article}\begin{document}    Priest: Dominus vobiscum.
    People: Et cum spiritu tuo.

    Priest: Sursum corda.
    People: Habemus ad Dominum.

    Priest: Gratias agamus Domino Deo nostro.
    People: Dignum et iustum est.\end{document} ;-)

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. I hope you manage to solve the issue!

Comment: @citshacots: Hello and Thank you for answering. That link answers my question. I'd like to add a new question using `Answering your question` to ask a new question that is linked at main one. Please Don't close these my questions, thank you.